# Classification of experimentally-determined physics laws?

Tags: physics, experimental-physics, resource-recommendation

Has anyone classified (or attempted to classify) all the experimentally-determined laws of physics, such as with a simple diagram or even in a full-length book?

Doing an ["experimental physics" subject search on WorldCat](https://www.worldcat.org/search?q=su%3A%22experimental%20physics%22&qt=results_page) doesn't reveal much.

Comment: (http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Administrivia/booklist.html) pick through this list; and reframe your question.  Do you have a time period in mind? Or are you looking for an encyclopedia? What would be the goal of such an undertaking?

Comment: @PeterDiehr _Do you have a time period in mind?_ from Aristotle to the present day. _Or are you looking for an encyclopedia?_ Yes _What would be the goal of such an undertaking?_ To show how experiments have made physics what it is today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[*A History of Mechanics*](http://store.doverpublications.com/0486656322.html), by Dugas (1955) is available from Dover; Part V is an introduction to Quantum Theory.  Some experiments are discussed, but it is mostly a scholarly discussion of ideas and how they evolved over time, with proper references, as explained by a trained engineer and historian of science.

The scope is well described by the preface and table of contents. Dugas references earlier compilers, and more detailed works of scholarship.

[History of electromagnetism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_electromagnetic_theory) is a Wikipedia resource, providing references.

Scholarpedia provides an open-access, peer reviewed [*Encyclopedia: Physics*](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Encyclopedia:Physics), which could keep you busy for a few years, or decades.  The content is intended to be "a living review" of each topic; it is not intended to provide a history of physics, but rather, the current state of it.

Comment: I'm familiar with Dugas's excellent work. Perhaps it is the closest to what I'm looking for.